# AngularJS directive that manually transcludes content and has isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I would like to hear the opinion of more experienced AngularJS developers on whether the following directive is best practice...

I was trying to make to make a directive that will include HTML that:

- Can include compiled elements (other directives, like ng-src in the
  example below)
- Interpolated values ({{ value }})
- Can include values/functions from the parent scope without modifying it (i.e. the
  directive has isolated scope)

Example usage:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<tag>
    <h1><a href="{{ url }}">{{ url }}</a></h1>
    <img ng-src="{{ image }}" />
</tag>
</div>
```

Controller and directive implementation:

```
var testapp = angular.module('testapp', []);

var Ctrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.url = "http://google.com";
    $scope.image = "https://www.google.gr/images/srpr/logo4w.png";
};

testapp.directive('tag', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: { },
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
        return function(scope) {
            transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone) {
                tElement.append(clone);
            });
        }
    }
  }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x5WcB/3/

Comment: Am i wrong or the third compile argument comes null? compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude)

Comment: You should use `link` here instead of `compile`. `link` gets passed the scope as the first argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit confused, your directive basically would do what Angular already does?

When I comment out the entire `testapp.directive('tag', function() {` block, I see no change in the functionality of this code in fiddle.. I think you need a more extensive example for us to provide a meaningful review.

Other than that:

- Your code looks fine to me
- JsHint.com cannot find anything wrong besides some missing semicolons
- You have 0 comments in your code

Comment: In this specific case there is no benefit, but a directive will often process information into a particular object and include extra methods. Eg. I could create a `tag` object within the directive and expose this as part of the isolated scope. The `tag` object might have useful methods such as `delete`, which removes the entire node. You could then add a button inside the `tag` node which invokes `tag.delete()`. Whether you use a link or a button or whatever to invoke it is left up to the html that consumes the directive, and isn't predetermined by the directive.

Comment: I honestly can't remember what I was thinking when I posted the question but I would like to believe that there was a reason why I wanted to do this manually and was just setting up a test case for it :)